# Can't connect to remote MongoDB

Tags: linux, mongodb, docker

I have a MongoDB instance running on a server in a container. I used the following command to run the container :
`docker run -dp 27017:27017 -v /opt/mongodb/data:/data/db --name mongodb mongo --auth --bind_ip_all`
The problem is that I can't connect to the instance unless I am connected on my server (i.e connect to localhost:27017), although I need to be able to connect to the instance from any IP, which is not working.

Any idea ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out that I was trying to connect to a 3.6 mongod instance with a 2.6 mongo shell. By upgrading my local mongo shell version everything went okay.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you running the linux server in DO or not. But you'll have to enable firewall like 'sudo allow ufw 27017' in my case for connecting to MongoDB. Hope this helps.

Comment: Sadly this did not resolve my problem. Thanks anyway.